# What happens to the poles of a bar magnet if it isn't completely broken in two, but only partially broken?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

At what point does it become two magnets instead of one?

Comment: The question of what defines an "object," and by extension whether a particular arrangement of matter is "one broken object" or "two objects" is an old question in philosophy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A magnet is not a single object. Internally it is made up of microscopic [magetic domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) that are in effect tiny individual bar magnets. The large magnet you hold in your hand is a composite of all the tiny magnetic domains.

So when you talk about breaking a magnet you aren't really breaking any magnets, just separating the domains. The result might look something like:

[image: Magnetic domains]

For the unbroken magnet the fields of all the individual domains add up to give nice clear North and South poles. For the partially broken magnet there will still be clear poles at the ends, but near the break the fields of the individual domains won't add up in a tidy way and the field will be somewhat messy. As you complete the break and pull the two halves apart the field near the break will settle down to give a new North and South pole at the broken ends.

Answer (score 2):

Magnet is said to split into two parts when the magnetic circuit is broken.In your case if the magnet is partially broken there is a fringing flux in the air gap but most of the field lines pass through the low reluctance path,which in the above case is the unbroken part.And if there has to be fringing of flux there has to be two unlike poles nearby and hence two poles are created as soon as the magnet is broken.Which may be very weak as most of the flux flows through the unbroken part.

Comment: Does this mean that if I imagine a rectangular magnet, North at the top and South at the bottom, and I chisel out a narrow rectangular volume half way between the poles (but not breaking the magnet), that there will be a weak South above the gap and a weak North above the gap due to fringing fields?